# Use linq to provide a running total of how many users existed by date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The premise for this is pretty simple, but I just can't seem to nail down how to describe this in linq. I am using EF, and I should be able to pull the data in a single query.

I have a user object with the following (simplified):

```
public class User
{
  public DateTime addDate;
  public int status;
  bool isActive
}
```

I want to create a report that takes a date range (i.e. startDate/endDate) that displays the following columns:

[image]

(the numbers don't add up, just for show)

The first column is the date, which the data is grouped by. The second is a running total for the number of user that had been added to the system at that time. The rest is a break down of the users first by the isActive bool, and then by the status.

Can I appeal to one of the linq gurus on SO for some help on this? I could just pull the data in and do it in code, but that's not optimal. I'd like to learn how this could be done in linq.

==================================

EDIT: I realized there was one piece I was not clear on. The numbers are not reflective of the number of members that joined that day, but rather the total to date. I believe I might be looking for an aggregate, but I'm not sure. Maybe a sum could work too.

So in the example, as of 1/13/14 there were 297 with an addDate of the 13th or earlier. On 1/14/14 no members were added, and finally on 1/15/14 three more users were added totaling 300 as of that date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the basic would be something like that, I would say...

```
var result = repository.Users
             .GroupBy(m => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(addDate))
             .Select(g => new {
                 Date = g.Key,
                 TotalMemberShip = g.Count(),
                 IsActiveWithStatus1 = g.Count(x => x.isActive && x.status == 1),
                 IsActiveWithStatus2 = g.Count(x => x.isActive && x.status == 2),
                 IsInactiveWithStatus1 = g.Count(x => !x.isActive && x.status == 1),
                 IsInactivewithStatus2 = g.Count(x => !x.isActive && x.status == 2)
             });
```

**EDIT** (from comment)

hmmm, I would try this, but absolutely not sure that this will work

same as before, just change the line

```
TotalMemberShip = repository.Users.Count(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(addDate) <= g.Key)
```

**EDIT 2**

Well, maybe rather this one (I use this syntax, which has the `let` keyword, if you need the "aggregation" for all your results).

```
from item in repository.Users
group item by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(addDate) into g
let datesBefore = repository.Users.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(addDate) <= g.Key)
select new {
  Date = g.Key,
  TotalMemberShip = datesBefore.Count(),
  IsActiveWithStatus1 = datesBefore.Count(x => x.isActive && x.status == 1),
  //etc.
  //if you need datas BEFORE (and equal) use datesBefore.Count
  //if you need datas "at the exact day" use g.Count
}
```

Comment: TruncateTime is nice... I was not aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewFlanagan discovered it this morning on SO ;)

Comment: Hey Raphael, thanks for taking the time to help me out. I think this is really close to what I want, but there is one piece I realized I was no clear enough on. I have updated the original post to be more clear. Do you know how I could integrate an aggregate or sum into this? Is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: @AndrewDunaway see edit maybe. I tested it on linq to objects, but I'm not sure it will work in linq to entities

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. You rock man, thank you. Even better I'm following what you did here, so I learned something today :)